# Is there a way to prevent the "missing firmware" problem showing up when upgrading kernel?

Tags: linux-kernel, firmware

I'm setting up my own server and I decide to customize my own kernel.

After `make install`, a warning message appears on the terminal:
 `W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/bxt_huc_ver01_8_2893.bin for module i915`

I know how to fix it after upgrading the kernel but I want to learn about **how to prevent it**. I don't know if there is a method can achieve such an effect, please let me know if there is one.

I will be very thankful to you.

Comment: If it’s not possible to disable that certain driver or part of it in the kernel configuration, patch it. Another possibility is to patch the code that prints a warning.

Comment: Install that firmware.

Comment: I think perhaps there is a way which can let kernel to auotomatically detect and download the missing firmware, in other words, let kernel to solve the problem without our intervention. Because we don't know which firmware will miss at next upgrade.

Comment: I just started learning linux and if I said something strange please forgive me.

Comment: @GhostDog When you're using distro kernels, the distro usually updates the kernel and the firmware packages so that you'll have all the firmware files the distro kernel needs. If you're installing your own mainline kernel, it might need firmware files that are not yet available through your distro packaging. The kernel will only look at the filesystem for the firmware, it certainly won't download anything!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer, install or upgrade `linux-firmware` to get that firmware.

The warning actually comes from `mkinitramfs(8)` hooks. It looks at the modules to be installed in the initramfs, and checks for all the potentially required firmware files listed by the modules using the `MODULE_FIRMWARE()` macro in the kernel source, and installs the firmware files in the initramfs alongside the modules. You get the warning if the firmware can't be found.

When the modules installed in the initramfs are probed, there is no rootfs available yet, and you might be missing firmware files required by the modules. Depending on the module and the firmware, there's a risk your newly installed kernel won't work.

If you install the firmware file to rootfs to fix the problem after the kernel install or upgrade, you'll need to run `update-initramfs(8)` to also copy the firmware to initramfs.

In this specific case, the i915 module would only use that module if you're running on Broxton platform, and even there it's not used by default.

The best option to prevent the warning is to have the firmware available in rootfs (typically under `/lib/firmware`) at kernel install time. Another option is to exclude the relevant module from initramfs, and probe it later from rootfs instead when it becomes available. Obviously you could also patch the tool to skip the warning, or patch the driver to not list the file using `MODULE_FIRMWARE()`, but they are hacks better avoided.

Comment: I downloaded `linux-5.2.5` kernel on `kernel.org`, it doesn't seems to have `/lib/firmware` folder......

Comment: @GhostDog The firmware are in separate repositories. Most are in linux-firmware which is https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.git/ and distros package that. For example in Debian there's https://packages.debian.org/buster/firmware-linux. There are also other repositories and packages for firmware. The firmware file are not shipped with the kernel.

Comment: So I need to select `Device Tree and Open Firmware support` when I customize kernel?

Comment: @GhostDog That would depend on your platform. It's not relevant for i915. You'll need "Firmware loader -> Firmware loading facility".